# How/where can I host a stellar-core watcher node outside of local?

Tags: stellar-core, nodes

I've recently gotten a stellar-core watcher node up on my local machine and built another separate console application to interact with the database. The database itself is hosted with Amazon RDS. The app is ready to go, I'm just looking to for a place to put it where it can run 24/7, or at least often enough to maintain a decently up to date version.

I built stellar-core from the provided visual studio solution on windows. I've tried bundling the exe with related dlls and sticking it into an azure webjob, but I can't seem to get it to run or debug it, despite success locally.

How do people normally host their nodes, is this something I would need a separate dedicated machine for, or are there cloud VM services that can just run an executable 24/7?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Amazon RDS already, [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2) instance is the best option. Amazon [offers](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) relatively cheap `t2.small` instances. If you are going to build some app that interacts with Stellar Core, consider using `c5.*` instances, which are better suited for applications with heavy CPU utilization.

By the way, Linux provides much better performance on cheap instances (and saves ~30% of budget). Here is a detailed walk-trough on [how to setup a stellar-core on Centos](https://galactictalk.org/d/20-setting-up-stellar-core-on-centos-7).

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the following "one-click" templates for deploying Stellar on AWS. The second one uses RDS for the database and EFS for local state.

The templates are still under development so they are wired to connect to the test network for now, but the plan is to continue make them more robust and production ready so you can keep an eye on the project:

https://github.com/starformlabs/stellar-nebulaforge-aws/tree/master/single-ec2
https://github.com/starformlabs/stellar-nebulaforge-aws/tree/master/single-ec2-single-rds